# Rows and column limit in textarea field HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In textarea field i have to implement following restrictions
1. textarea rows limit is 6
2. textarea cols limit is 20
3. if any row exceeded 20 length that row will split in two rows if row available

My Code:

```
function limitTextareaLine(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13
            && $(this).val().split("\n").length >= $(this).attr('rows')) {
        return false;
    }
    var result = "";
    var textArray = $(this).val().split("\n");
    alert(textArray.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) { //Unable to iterate loop
        if (textArray[i].length > 5) {
            alert('aaa');
            if (textArray.length == 6) {
                alert("nnnnn");
                return false;
            }
            result += textArray[i] + "\n";
        } else {
            result += textArray[i];
        }
        alert(textArray[i])
    }
    for ( var line in textArray) {

    }
    alert(result);
    $(this).val(result);
}

$(function() {
    $('textarea.limited').keydown(limitTextareaLine);
});

<textarea rows="6" cols="20" class="limited"></textarea>
```

In above code loop is not working. Only first line will iterate.
Please suggest if there is any better way to do this.

My requirement is textarea filed have max 6 lines and each line have max char is 20. if any line exceeded the max char limit the split into two lines if max line limit is available.

Comment: No JS required, just use the `wrap="hard"` attribute in your HTML

Comment: I think your problem may be with your textArray variable.  The split function creates an array for every split.  So maybe try 'i < textArray[0].length'. I don't know which part of the array you want.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan then row limit will exceeded .. i need max 6 lines and each line max char is 20. if any line exceeded the max char limit the split into two lines if max line limit is avalible

Comment: Ah. In that case I'd suggest using 6 textboxes with `maxlength="20"`

Comment: This should do th trick : `<textarea rows="6" cols="19" class="limited" maxlength="120"></textarea>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: My point is what limiting to 120 characters doesn't stop more rows being added. Also, please don't use W3Schools as a reference.

Comment: He want it to restrict to only 6 rows with 20 char each, so the total will be max 120. so by giving `rows="6"` and `cols="19"` it can be acheived with maxlength.

Comment: @MakarandPatil in this case you can insert more then 10 lines of length 5. rows="6" will not restrict the rows limit.

Comment: @gifpif : i didn't thought about that case. thank you for reminding me buddy :) My solution won't work in that case

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays, it [doesn't guarantee the order it iterates in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)! Instead use `Array.prototype.forEach`,`for`, or `for...of`. Depending on what you are doing something like `Array.prototype.reduce` might work too.

Comment: The `return false` after `alert("nnnnn");` is what is causing it to only process one line. `return` causes the function to return, ending the loop then and there. What is your expected behavior? Do you want it to just return `true` or `false` so you can display an error? Do you want it to automatically wrap when a line is too long? Do you want it to ignore the enter key once you hit 6 lines?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, this may be what you're looking for.

```js
function limitTextareaLine(e) {
  const newLine = /\r*\n/g;
  const value = e.target.value;
  const newLines = (value.match(newLine) || []).length;

  const lines = value.split(newLine);

  //enter
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && lines.length >= e.target.rows) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  const lineNo = value.substr(0, e.target.selectionStart).split(newLine).length - 1;

  //backspace
  if (e.keyCode === 8 && ~value.charAt(e.target.selectionStart - 1).search(newLine)) {
    if (lines[lineNo].length + lines[lineNo - 1].length <= e.target.cols) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  //del
  if (e.keyCode === 46 && ~value.charAt(e.target.selectionStart).search(newLine)) {
    if (lines[lineNo].length + lines[lineNo + 1].length <= e.target.cols) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (e.key.length > 1) return;

  if (value.length < e.target.cols) return;

  if (lines[lineNo].length > e.target.cols - 1) {
    if (lines.length < e.target.rows) {
      const col = (e.target.selectionStart - newLines) / lines.length;
      let p1 = value.substr(0, e.target.selectionStart);
      if (col === e.target.cols) {
        p1 += '\r\n' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
      } else {
        p1 += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '\r\n';
      }

      e.target.value = p1 + value.substr(e.target.selectionStart, value.length);
      e.target.selectionStart = p1.length - 1;
      e.target.selectionEnd = p1.length - 1;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('textarea.limited').addEventListener('keydown', limitTextareaLine);
});
```

```css
.limited {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="3" rows="4" class="limited"></textarea>
```

I want to say that I'm totally unhappy with this code and I'm pretty sure there are some more maintainable and elegant way of doing something like this.

Still, I think you can work with this as an example of how you **could** do what you want.