# Javascript for loop not working on function keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code for alert all the lines of textarea filed on every keydown event but loop not working

```
function limitTextareaLine(e) {

  var textArray = $(this).val().split("\n");
  for(var v in textArray){ // Only iterate first line
    alert(textArray[v] +" "+textArray.length); 
  }

}

$(function() {
    $('textarea.limited').keydown(limitTextareaLine);
});
```

Comment: is this question related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072290/rows-and-column-limit-in-textarea-field-html

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: @RobAnthony Iterate all lines of textarea filed on each char inserted in textarea

Comment: use for .. of maybe?

Comment: I've copied the code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06abanh5/1/) and it works fine. PS use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you need to loop through the array using numbers, you were using the values in the array. You need the following:

```
function limitTextareaLine(e) {

  var textArray = $(this).val().split("\n");
  for(v=0; v < textArray.length; v++){
    alert(textArray[v] +" "+textArray.length); 
  }

}

$(function() {
    $('textarea.limited').keyup(limitTextareaLine);
});
```

I've also changed the event to keyup so that it triggers the event after the key has been recorded in the box.